# Convert QString to QChar in Qt version 5.3

Tags: c++, qt

So I've had to work on an assignment for uni, and it has to be done in Qt 5.3. I've written the program in version 5.13 and simply used the .back() function to convert from QString to QChar. However, I find out that we must use 5.3 and this function was only introduced in 5.10.

Are there any other ways to do this? Already tried toAscii(), toLatin1(), but nothing works. Also, I'm not trying to convert to char*.

```
cout << "Enter latitude coordinates: " << endl;
    input_lat = cin.readLine();

    QList<QString> lat_list = input_lat.split(" ");

    int d_lat = lat_list[0].toInt();
    int m_lat = lat_list[1].toInt();
    int s_lat = lat_list[2].toInt();
    QChar dir_lat = lat_list[3].back().toUpper();
```

This was working fine in Qt 5.13.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#back) tells you how to replace this function:

> Returns the last character in the string. Same as at(size() - 1).

Comment: Hi @chehrlic,

Thanks for the input. 

I've tried this

`QChar dir_lat = lat_list.at(lat_list.size() - 1);`


Get an error: conversion from 'const QString' to non-scalar type 'QChar' requested

Comment: Because you're now working on the QList<QString>. You want to work on lat_list[3]